# Oracle PL SQL function has no INTO clause, but it actually has a SELECT INTO

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a function inside a package.

The body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_developers AS

     FUNCTION lookup_developer_studio(p_studio_name IN DEVELOPERSTUDIOS.STUDIONAME%type)
            RETURN INTEGER
        IS
            f_developerstudioid INTEGER;
        BEGIN
            SELECT developerstudioid INTO f_developerstudioid
            FROM developerStudios
            WHERE studioName = p_studio_name;
            RETURN (f_developerstudioid);
        END lookup_developer_studio;
END pkg_developers;
```

The header:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_developers
AS

    FUNCTION lookup_developer_studio(p_studio_name IN DEVELOPERSTUDIOS.STUDIONAME%type) RETURN INTEGER;
END pkg_developers;
```

I'm testing the function like so:

```
BEGIN
    select pkg_developers.lookup_developer_studio('some name') from dual;
END;
```

The Error I get:

```
[2022-04-16 13:06:06] [65000][6550]
[2022-04-16 13:06:06]   ORA-06550: line 6, column 5:
[2022-04-16 13:06:06]   PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
[2022-04-16 13:06:06] Summary: 1 of 1 statements executed, 1 failed in 15 ms (285 symbols in file)
```

But as far as I can see, I do have an INTO clause?

When I run the query statically like: `SELECT developerstudioid FROM developerStudios WHERE studioName = 'some name';` I do get 1 result which is an integer.

Comment: SELECT (you used to test the function) says that function is part of the package. FUNCTION code you posted doesn't suggest that (but OK, you might have extracted that piece of code out of the package body) and yes - it has an INTO clause so it looks OK.  Can you verify that you're calling the *right* function?

Comment: @Littlefoot The function is indeed part of a package, I updated the question to include the package body & header. And I since it's the only function with that name it should be the correct function that gets called.

Comment: it is definitely that function that gets called, I just changed the name to check, updated the body, header and called it again and still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, code you used to **test** it isn't equal to what you initially posted - this is actually a **PL/SQL** block which then requires an `INTO` clause:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2      select pkg_developers.lookup_developer_studio('some name') from dual;
  3  END;
  4  /
    select pkg_developers.lookup_developer_studio('some name') from dual;
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

If it were only `SELECT` (at SQL level) then yes - you don't need `INTO`:

```
SQL> select * from developerstudios;

STU DEVELOPERSTUDIOID
--- -----------------
MGM               100

SQL>     select pkg_developers.lookup_developer_studio('MGM') from dual;

PKG_DEVELOPERS.LOOKUP_DEVELOPER_STUDIO('MGM')
---------------------------------------------
                                          100

SQL>
```

If you want PL/SQL, then declare a variable which will store that value:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2    l_id developerstudios.developerstudioid%type;
  3  BEGIN
  4      select pkg_developers.lookup_developer_studio('MGM') INTO l_id from dual;
  5      dbms_output.put_line('Result = ' || l_id);
  6  END;
  7  /
Result = 100

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```